# How can I combine an IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable) using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I've got a `List(Of HashSet(Of String))`. Is there a clear, one-line LINQ way to get a single `HashSet(Of String)` containing all the strings in the list entry values?

For example, from the 3 hashsets {"A"}, {"A","B","C"}, and {"B","C","D"} I'd like a single hashset {"A","B","C","D"}.

I'm pretty sure I can do something with `.Aggregate()` or `.Accumulate()`.

C# or VB.NET explanations are equally helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In C#:

```
var newHashSet = new HashSet<string>(myListOfHashSets.SelectMany(x => x));
```

And in VB.NET:

```
Dim newHashSet As New HashSet(Of String)(myListOfHashSets.SelectMany(Function (x) x))
```

Comment: @CSharpie Not necessary. `Distinct` essentially creates a hash set, then enumerates it, so just selecting into a new hash set saves one step.

Comment: This will not return a distinct list, as required in the question. Add a call to Distinct.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I'm surprised no exceptions are thrown though :)

Comment: @Crono1981 Hash sets don't throw exceptions if you try to add an element that already exists, it just returns false. This is one of the  reasons hash sets are particularly useful.

Comment: Yeah but for constructors there's no way to catch that information back, so I'm still surprised. This is something to remember when creating hashsets: it won't necessarily have the same object count as the original list. :)

Answer (score 2):

`SelectMany` does exactly this. At a high level (omitting the generics and simplifying a bit), `SelectMany` is implemented like:

```
static IEnumerable SelectMany(this source, Func selector)
{
    IEnumerable results;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        foreach (var result in selector(item))
        {
            results.add(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

*The above code is not actually accurate; instead it uses a yield return to perform the select lazily and uses no intermediate collection `results`. Finally, the full signature is actually `public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)`, but the only important piece to understand is that selector returns a collection. If you have a collection of collections then using the identity function `x => x` does exactly that.*

So, it flattens collections of collections into a single collection. Using the identity function `x => x` as the selector means that the elements of the inner collections are unchanged. So, as a few others have posted, the final answer would be:

```
var newSet = new HashSet(setOfSets.SelectMany(element => element));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using UnionWith method of HashSet. It will be something like this:

```
var result = myListOfHashSets.Aggregate(new HashSet<string>(), (x, y) => { x.UnionWith(y); return x; });
```